# Why does this seemingly simple C++ code generate a segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, class, reference, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to write a boosting algorithm (a feature of artificial intelligence). Speed is a priority, so I've switched from using my native Python to C++. I wrote the entire program out, but I got a bug that I whittled down to a fault I made in the base class: a very simple heuristic called "H." The files h.h, h.cpp, and my current testing function main.cpp are:

```
//h.h

#ifndef __H_H_INCLUDED__
#define __H_H_INCLUDED__

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class H
{
    public:
        H(int, double, bool);
        //The first parameter is the axis
        //The second parameter is the cutoff
        //The third parameter is the direction
        bool evaluate(std::vector<double>&);
        //This evaluates the heuristic at a given point.
    private:
        int axis;
        double cutoff;
        bool direction;
};

#endif

//h.cpp

#include "h.h"

H::H(int ax, double cut, bool d)
{
    axis = ax;
    cutoff = cut;
    direction = d;
}

bool H::evaluate(std::vector<double>& point)
{
    if (direction)
    {
        return point[axis] > cutoff;
    }
    else
    {
        return point[axis] <= cutoff;
    }
}

//main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "h.h"

int main()
{
    H h(0, 2.0, true);
    for (double x = 0; x < 4; x = x + 1)
    {
        for (double y = 0; y < 4; y = y + 1)
        {
            std::vector<double> point(x, y);
            std::vector<double>& point_ref = point;
            std::cout << "Before computation" << std::endl;
            bool value = h.evaluate(point_ref);
            std::cout << "After computation" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "heuristic(x = " << x << ", y = " << y << ") = " << value << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

(I put the "Before computation" and "After computation" in to pinpoint which line the error occurs on.) Quite contrary to the output I would expect, I get:

```
 Before computation
 Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What did I do wrong? What does that error message even mean?
Thanks!

EDIT: I'm using C++11, just for those who are curious.

Comment: your vector `point` is empty. push back x and y to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line:

```
std::vector<double> point(x, y);
```

Makes a `vector` with `x` copies of `y`. It's [constructor #2 here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector). So when `x` is 0, `point` is an empty `vector` - which means your access of the element at index 0 is undefined behavior, in this case exhibited by a segmentation fault.

What you probably had intended to do was to make a vector containing the two values `x` and `y`, which would be:

```
std::vector<double> point{x, y}; // in c++11, note the braces

std::vector<double> point(2);    // pre-c++11
point[0] = x;
point[1] = y;
```